# Is there any way to crack a password-protected disk image?

Tags: macos, password, keychain, dmg

I have created a .dmg file with password. Unfortunately I forgot the password and I my Google searches have not resulted in a way to reset the password of this .dmg file.

Please help me find a solution. I desperately need to access the contents of this .dmg file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An article written by someone else who did that:

http://blog.whitehatsec.com/cracking-aes-256-dmgs-and-epic-self-pwnage/

The author did get his cracked, but had to borrow a supercomputer to do so even after he got custom software designed to use partial knowledge of the password he had chosen.

It shows how hard a general cracking effort would be, but also how choosing a short or known pass phrase makes it practical in some cases to hire an expert to bypass even a good solid encryption scheme.

Comment: Archived version of article: https://web.archive.org/web/20190423115507/https://www.whitehatsec.com/blog/cracking-aes-256-dmgs-and-epic-self-pwnage/

Answer (score 2):

Because the files are encrypted using AES, it'll take a really really really REALLY long time to crack the password if your password isn't in the dictionaries, so it's safe to assume your files are gone forever.

However, applications such as Spartan will attempt to crack DMGs if you really want the files inside.